# RedisException: Read error on connection with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, redis

I'm getting this constant exception when running the static content deploy command and here is my redis section from the env.php file

```
'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => 
    array (
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '6379',
      'password' => '',
      'timeout' => '3.5',
      'persistent_identifier' => '',
      'database' => '0',
      'compression_threshold' => '2048',
      'compression_library' => 'gzip',
      'log_level' => '1',
      'max_concurrency' => '6',
      'break_after_frontend' => '5',
      'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
      'first_lifetime' => '600',
      'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
      'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
      'disable_locking' => '0',
      'min_lifetime' => '60',
      'max_lifetime' => '2592000',
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we had a similar error after the upgrade to 2.1.6 when deploying static files.

It seemed like throwing a random exception not be able to access the redis cache.

It seems to be a problem with the parallel procession of the static files compilation.

For now, as a workaround, we are deploying the files with the -j 1 option, to only start one process:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -j 1
```

Comment: The issue is still present on 2.2.2 version of Magento. Even `-j 1` doesn't help.